# Can't find a way to deal with Google Drive API 403 Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I have a huge amount of users and files in a Google Drive domain. +100k users, +10M of files. I need to fetch all the permissions for these files every month.

Each user have files owned by themselves, and files shared by other domain users and/or external users (users that don't belong to the domain). Most of the files are owned by domain users. There is more than 7 millions of unique files owned by domain users.

My app is a backend app, which runs with a token granted by the domain admin user.

I think that doing batch requests is the best way to do this. Then, I configured  my app to 1000 requests per user, in google developer console.

I tried the following cases:

1. 1000 requests per batch, up to 1000 per user -> lots of user rate limits
2. 1000 requests per batch, up to 100 per user -> lots of rate limit errors
3. 100 requests per batch, up to 100 per user -> lots of rate limit errors
4. 100 requests per batch, up to 50 per user -> lots of rate limits errors
5. 100 requests per batch, up to 10 per user -> not errors anymore

I'm using quotaUser parameter to uniquely identify each user in batch requests.

I checked my app to confirm that each batch was not going to google out of its time. I checked also to see if each batch have no more than the limit of file_id configured to fetch. Everything was right.

I also wait each batch to finish before sending the next one.

Every time I see a 403 Rate Limit Exceeded, I do an exponential backoff. Sometimes I have to retry after 9 steps, which is 2**9 seconds waiting.

So, I can't see the point of Google Drive API limits. I'm sure my app is doing everything right, but I can't increase the limits to fetch more permissions per second.

Comment: not clear if each user has different files, if they are owned by the user or a single google account, and if you are doing the requests with the user's access token or the same token for all users.

Comment: @ZigMandel I am pretty sure user rate is controlled either by the UserIP or quotaUser  parameters it shouldn't matter who owns the file.  This is something we could test.

Comment: Have you tried going into the Google Developers console APIs -> google Drive -> quota and increasing the Per-user limit?

Comment: yes what i asked matters a lot. answer all those questions and maybe i can help

Comment: @ZigMandel there is +7M unique files, there is also a lot of files shared between users, but my app is smart enough to skip them. I'm using the same token to fetch permission on behalf each domain user.

Comment: @DalmTo I configured my app to 1000 request per second, per user. Google just ignores that configuration.

Comment: still not clear. are all users in the same google domain? are the files owned by them or a single account? if also makes sense that increasing the user rate limit wont help, because that only helps if one user spikes, not all. also dont use exp. backoff that's only for abnormal spike situations.

Comment: @ZigMandel yes. All users are in same google domain. I edited the question to clarify the situation of files owned by users.

Comment: when impersonating, you are actually using a single account for all requests, not the user account itself. ive also struggled with rate limits in this case and also found the console setting was ignored. I think what you need is to have stored each user's refresh token beforehand and use the actual user account in a regular 3legged flow. not trivial to collect the tokens but possible for example by deploying a chrome extension domain wide which asks all users for the permission.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a limit that google sets to stop people spamming the service and tying it up. It doesn't have anything to do with your app itself but is set on the Google server side. If the Google server receives over a particular number of requests within a certain time this is the error you get. There is nothing you can do in your app to overcome this. You can talk to Google about it and usually paying for Google licenses ect can allow you much higher limits before being restricted.